# SharePoint 2007 Workflow

Tags: designer-workflow

I need to create workflow where many item are there and  to send out an alert to my mailbox every time, when “Planned End Date” has been reached. as given below in table.

[image]

Can you please help..

Answer (score 0):

This is not a workflow.

Create a timer job to check the documents in the library every day for the planned end date.

Comment: Thanks Yandr...I tried to do it in many ways that. I went SharePoint Designer and created workflow and given condition "If Planned End Date" = "Current date" then send email to .... but it's dint work...as you are telling how can do that.can you pls. elaborate..

Comment: I tried to do it in many ways that. I went SharePoint Designer and created workflow and given condition "If Planned End Date" = "Current date" then send email to ....but it's dint work...as you are telling how can do that.can you pls. elaborate.. ?